# Use ROS custom messages outside catkin workplace with CMake

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, ros, build-system

**Question:** Whats the best practice to include generated ros messages/services in code outside catkin workplace, in CMakeLists.txt?

Context: 
So in the current project I've started working on, the build system is based on CMake but *some* of the codes/executable's uses ROS. I've decided to follow the same pattern, and create most of the executables outside ROS catkin workplace. Now due to some new requirement I needed to create my own ROS message/services, and have added those as packages in the catkin workplace, and generate them using catkin_make. The directory tree is as below

```
root
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-src
|-|--myExecutable.cpp
|-catkin_ws
|--|--src
|--|--|--myPackage
|--|--|---|--srv
|--|--|---|--msg
|--|--|---|--package.xml
|--|--|---|--CMakeLists.txt
|-otherLibraries
|--|--CMakeLists.txt
```

Now, for my own usage I just run `catkin_make` once to generate the header files for msg/srv and `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` (actually added to my `~/.bashrc`) for building the project, with the top CMakeLists.txt. In the top CMakeLists.txt I have `find_package(myPackage)` and this works fine for my usage, `myExecutable.cpp` which uses the message/service defined in `myPackage` and libraries made by others in `otherLibraries` compiles and run just fine.

Now another member of the project which uses *Visual Studio Code* complained that `find_package(myPackage)` gives error on his IDE CMake tools. I know that this is caused by `source catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` not being run on the IDE.

My CMake knowledge is a patchwork at best, but I know that people in the project prefer [Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/) and I'm not sure whats the best practice to solve this. (Should I run the `setup.bash` script inside the top CMakeLists.txt? Should I manually add the location of the generated header/lib using `set()`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar case where I was using some C++ libraries independent of ROS and then I had the need to use ROS.

What I ended-up doing was to create a catkin package in my `catkin_ws` for my software and alter the `CMakeLists.txt` for the non-ROS needs. This way I am using `catkin_make` to build the entire project including ROS-related stuff and non-ROS related stuff. In fact, the case I am talking about is open-source [here](https://github.com/rpapallas/hitl_clutter), you can have a look.

You can then let your IDE know where to look and it should pick up everything. Personally, I opened my catkin package in CLion IDE and CLion picked-up everything. I was able to build, compile, run and debug within the same IDE without a hassle, it really is a great setup for my needs (bridging ROS and non-ROS code, fully functional IDE with debugging tools!).

The icing on the cake is that I did all the above within a Singularity container. Having all these in a single singularity container is very *portable* and *shareable*. You take/share the Singularity recipe or even a pre-built Singularity image, anyone can use it on their computer and have the exact same configuration as yours! We have an example of such Singularity configuration on GitHub [here](https://github.com/roboticsleeds/ur5controller_singularity) to provide a fully functional and contained UR5 controller for OpenRAVE.

Comment: Hi Rafael! Thank you very much for the feedback! Just to clarify: When you say use ```catkin_ws``` for your software and alter ```CMakeLists.txt```, do you mean that you essentially moved up (in the above structure) ```myExecutable.cpp``` and ```otherLibraries``` to the ```catkin_ws``` **as a new package**, and added the CMakeLists.txt content from the root there?

Comment: If myPackage makes sense to be merged with myExecutable and otherLibraries, then move myExecutable in the src of myPackage and otherLibraries into myPackage and merge the CMakeLists outside myPackage into myPackage. Alternatively, if it doesn’t make sense to put everything in myPackage keep myPackage as is, and create a new catkin package with just myExecutable and otherLibraries and again merge the CmakeLists outside to the new package’s CMakeLists.

Comment: I have an example on GitHub, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hello Rafael! Thank you for the clarification :) I'll put the answer as accepted. :) I think I will probably go with the way you mentioned it, the second option. (I will keep ```myPackage```Separate, with its own revision control system and repo). For now with some ugly tinkering, breaking the modern cmake way I got IDE working with the above condition but your way is definitely more maintainable. Thank you! :D

Comment: Glad that you sorted this out! Good luck!